# Is it possible to find similarities between rows in a matrix without loop?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, broadcasting

i have a 2D numpy array. I'm trying to compute the similarities between rows and put it into a `similarities` array. Is this possible without loop? Thanks for your time!

```
# ratings.shape = (943, 1682)

arri = np.zeros(943)
arri = np.where(arri == 0)[0]

arrj = np.zeros(943)
arrj = np.where(arrj ==0)[0]

similarities = np.zeros((ratings.shape[0], ratings.shape[0]))

similarities[arri, arrj] = np.abs(ratings[arri]-ratings[arrj])
```

I want to make a 2D-array similarities in that similarities[i, j] is the differentiation between row i and row j in ratings

[ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (943,1682)  could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (943,)]
[1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtst9.png

Comment: I want to make a 2D-array ```similarities``` in that similarities[i, j] is the differentiation between row i and row j in ```ratings```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is how numpy iterates through the array when indexing a two-dimentional array with two arrays.

---

First some setup:

```py
import numpy;

ratings = numpy.arange(1, 6)

indicesX = numpy.indices((ratings.shape[0],1))[0]
indicesY = numpy.indices((ratings.shape[0],1))[0]
```

`ratings`: `[1 2 3 4 5]`

`indicesX`: `[[0][1][2][3][4]]`

`indicesY`: `[[0][1][2][3][4]]`

---

Now lets see what your program produces:

```py
similarities = numpy.zeros((ratings.shape[0], ratings.shape[0]))
similarities[indicesX, indicesY] = numpy.abs(ratings[indicesX]-ratings[0])
```

`similarities`:

```py
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 2. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 3. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 4.]]
```

As you can see, numpy iterates over `similarities` basically like the following:

```py
for i in range(5):
    similarities[indicesX[i], indicesY[i]] = numpy.abs(ratings[i]-ratings[0])
```

`similarities`:

```py
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 2. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 3. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 4.]]
```

---

Now instead we need indices like the following to iterate through the entire array:

```py
indecesX = [0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4]
indecesY = [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4]
```

We do that the following:

```py
# Reshape indicesX from (x,1) to (x,). Thats important for numpy.tile().
indicesX = indicesX.reshape(indicesX.shape[0])
indicesX = numpy.tile(indicesX, ratings.shape[0])

indicesY = numpy.repeat(indicesY, ratings.shape[0])
```

`indicesX`: `[0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 4 0 1 2 3 4]`

`indicesY`: `[0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4]`

Perfect! Now just call `similarities[indicesX, indicesY] = numpy.abs(ratings[indicesX]-ratings[indicesY])` again and we see:

`similarities`:

```py
[[0. 1. 2. 3. 4.]
 [1. 0. 1. 2. 3.]
 [2. 1. 0. 1. 2.]
 [3. 2. 1. 0. 1.]
 [4. 3. 2. 1. 0.]]
```

---

Here the whole code again:

```py
import numpy;

ratings = numpy.arange(1, 6)

indicesX = numpy.indices((ratings.shape[0],1))[0]
indicesY = numpy.indices((ratings.shape[0],1))[0]

similarities = numpy.zeros((ratings.shape[0], ratings.shape[0]))

indicesX = indicesX.reshape(indicesX.shape[0])
indicesX = numpy.tile(indicesX, ratings.shape[0])

indicesY = numpy.repeat(indicesY, ratings.shape[0])

similarities[indicesX, indicesY] = numpy.abs(ratings[indicesX]-ratings[indicesY])
print(similarities)
```

### PS

You commented on your own post to improve it. You should edit your question instead of commenting on it, when you want to improve it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your explanation is nice and easy to understand. I got it. You save me :D. Thanks for all!

Comment: I'm happy I could help you :). Maybe you can accept my answer (would be my first accepted)!

Comment: I accepted it. This is also my first question :D